# Is it okay to cite a Wikipedia page address as a definition of a concept used in my thesis?

Tags: thesis, wikipedia

I'm using a concept in part of my thesis that is not very well-known, so it's good to give an explanation before going through the rest of the thesis. I'm wondering if I can simply give a Wikipedia page reference for it, so that readers who are not familiar with it can have a look at the given page. For example, let's say I'm using some stuff about Quaternions, can I just add a footnote to the page \footnote{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion} instead of repeating the same material in my thesis?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate, see other related questions: http://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=cite+wikipedia+is%3Aquestion

Comment: @Ehsan What do you feel is not addressed by the recommendations in the linked post?  Can you please clarify your concern?